# How to declare bound cursor with customized column name in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to use cursor in a function with the table name as a function variable, a simple example would be a select query through cursor.

From the documentation of PostgreSQL I found that I can use

```
Declare curs3 CURSOR (key integer) FOR SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 = key;
```

But when I input

```
declare curs1 cursor (key integer) for execute 'select ' || quote_ident(colname) || ' from ' || quote_ident(tablename);
```

It returns `ERROR: syntax error at or near "'select '"`.

On the other hand, if I write the function with `refcursor` as follows:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION cursor_hw(colname text,tablename text) RETURNS setof text  AS $$

declare curs1 refcursor;
BEGIN
  open curs1 for execute 'select ' || quote_ident(colname) || ' from ' || quote_ident(tablename);
  for x in curs1 loop
    return next x;
  end loop;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It will return `[42601] ERROR: cursor FOR loop must use a bound cursor variable`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prefer a simple `FOR record_variable IN  EXECUTE <query>`  instead of `OPEN FETCH` for dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION cursor_hw(colname text,tablename text) 
RETURNS setof text  AS 
$$
DECLARE 
x RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN  execute  'select ' || quote_ident(colname) || ' from ' 
                               || quote_ident(tablename)
   LOOP
      IF x.first_name like 'D%' THEN
        RETURN NEXT x;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**execution**

```
knayak=# select cursor_hw('first_name','employees');
 cursor_hw
-----------
 Donald
 Douglas
 David
 Diana
 Daniel
 Den
 David
 Danielle
 David
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but what should I do if I need to get one column of the record, e.g.  `x.id` ?